# Finding probability of uniform random variable given a condition with another random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose X and Y are independent and uniformly distributed on the unit interval (0,1). Find: $$P[Y>\frac{1}{2}\,|\,Y>1-2X]$$

How I approached it was to find the area where $Y > 1 - 2X$, and used that as my denominator. I then found the area where $Y > \frac{1}{2}$ within that area, and used that as the numerator. Upon dividing I get a value of 1/2, but apparently the answer is 7/12. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Your approach is good, perhaps calculations are off.  I get $\frac7{12}$.  Why don't you mention what numerator and denominator you get.

Comment: The area where Y > 1/2 is 1/2, and the area where Y > 1-2X is 3/4 (at least according to myself)

Comment: Actually I got that the area Y > 1/2 is equal to 3/8, and that's how I got a final answer of 1/2.

Comment: That's not correct either.  If you draw it, you should get a trapezium with corners $(\frac14, \frac12), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, \frac12)$. Do you get this?  Then the remainder is measuring its area.

Comment: I drew my graph inaccurately which led me to calculate the area of the trapezium wrong. In order to safeguard against this, how can I set up an integral to check my work?

Comment: Would it be something along the lines of $\int_0^1 \int_{1-2x}^1 ~dy dx$?

Comment: I have drawn the figure below.  Your integral does not work as it does not restrict $y > \frac12$. If you need an integral, try $\int_{\frac12}^1 \int_{\frac{1-y}2}^1 dx dy$.

Answer (score 1):

The geometry is illustrated below.

[image: The relevant areas]

The red shaded area is your numerator, and the blue shaded area your denominator.